Open Data of Hebrew words appearing in Old Testament?
This website https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2451.htm has stuff like this (notice the Englishman's Concordance on the right):

Is this data available in unicode text format somewhere/somehow? Like in JSON/XML/CSV/etc., for free use?
I am basically looking for the example sentences, with the word highlighted, in English and Hebrew, in a format I can use in code (JSON/XML/CSV/etc.).
